# Ubuntu 13.10 dual monitor setup

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors

Using Ubuntu 13.10, I'm trying to setup a second monitor. My installation is working just fine. In System Settings > Displays all the options are working properly. "Mirror Displays" is unchecked, the external monitor is recognized. After selecting desired resolution and applying I get an error message stating the requested size exceeds 3d hardware limit and I need to either change it or switch to 2D. No problem, I understand that completely. I looked through other posted questions to find how to switch to 2D. One answer stated to click the Ubuntu icon next to the username on the login screen and select it from there. The problem is, there is no Ubuntu icon on the login screen; just the couple of basic options in the top-right corner. But none of those are applicable. So how do I change the resolution limit or switch to 2D?

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2d is not included on newer versions of Ubuntu (anything after 12.04 I think).  You can install it if you wish too though.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```

This adds the PPA and installs unity 2d.  After a restart or logout you can switch your user interface.  The box with your password field will have a little unity symbol on the top right which will change it.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. If Unity 2D is not included on newer versions then is there no other way to run an extended desktop on newer versions? I tried to install Unity 2D as you instructed. Unfortunately after entering the first line I received a return stating:
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:unity-team/staging'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
Any other suggestions? Is there not a way to change the default resolution limit?

Comment: After browsing the forums it seems this fix doesn't work on 13, only 12.10 or earlier. Unfortunately it looks like 2d is completely incompatible with 13.10. The only advice I can offer is to try a different user interface like kde, lxde, or gnome. I personally like lxde. Of course someone may know a fix do keep an eye here. If you would like to see the discussion I referenced it's here (first response offers an alternative as well): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143639